# Short buffer name

Tags: vimrc, buffers, statusline

Is there a way to shorten the displayed name of the buffer, for example, on the image, path(...)/application_controller.rb to simply "application_controller.rb"?
If I have many buffers with such long names, things get messy.

My buffer menu :

```
set wildmenu  

set wildmode=longest:full,full  

set wildcharm='<'C-Y>  

nnoremap '<'F3> :b '<'C-Y><right>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is shorten the filename shown on the status line, search `statusline` or `stl` in your `vimrc`, and replace `%f` with `%t`.  See `:help statusline` for details.

Answer (score 1):

As the path that is shown in the *statusline* by default is relative to the current working directory, you could shorten it by `:cd`'ing to a "closer" subdirectory, or the file's directory itself (`:cd %:p:h`). With `:set autochdir`, this will be done automatically whenever you switch buffers.

Of course, this is a more invasive change than simply changing the `'statusline'` display itself.